Linearity Condition on Quantum Operations
I'm trying to understand quantum operations. At present, I understand that a quantum register composed of $m$ qubits is a superposition of $2^m$ basic states, and is represented as a vector $\boldsymbol{v} = \langle \boldsymbol{v}_{0^m}, \boldsymbol{v}_{0^{m-1}1}, ..., \boldsymbol{v}_{1^m} \rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{2^m}$. That is, if $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$ is the vector $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$ in the definition of $\boldsymbol{v}$ (i.e.  $\boldsymbol{v} = \langle ..., \boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}, ...\rangle$), then $b(i)$, the index of $\boldsymbol{v}_{b(i)}$, is the binary representation of the integer $i$, and $|b(i) \rangle$ is the $i$th basic state of the quantum register. What I don't understand is the restrictions on operations on quantum registers. Such operations must conform to the condition of linearity. So, with an $m$-qubit quantum register represented by $\boldsymbol{v} \in \mathbb{C}^{2^m}$, and with $F: \mathbb{C}^{2^m} \to \mathbb{C}^{2^m}$ being a quantum operation (respresented as a matrix) on $\boldsymbol{v}$, the text I'm reading says that $F$ satisfying the linearity condition requires that $F(\boldsymbol{v}) = \Sigma_x F(|\boldsymbol{v}_x \rangle)$. But I feel I must be missing something here because I don't see how $F(\boldsymbol{v})$ can even have the same dimensions as $\Sigma_x F(|\boldsymbol{v}_x \rangle)$; in fact, I don't even see how $F(|\boldsymbol{v}_x \rangle)$ can be allowed in linear algebra, because the dimensions of $F$ and $|\boldsymbol{v}_x \rangle$ are not compatible with respect to matrix mulitplication.
